# Installing Node on Ubuntu Mate 32bit system

Tags: ubuntu-mate, nodejs

I am trying to install node on an Ubuntu Mate (16.04) system running on 32bit .  Why can't I install node using `apt-get install node`?  I see that I have nodejs in the package manager and have installed it successfully and it creates usr/bin/nodejs.  However, when I run npm start on an app, it is looking for node in usr/bin/env and there is no usr/bin/env directory.

Also, installing nodejs does not seem to also include npm...

Comment: I don't know the specific software, but in my 16.04 LTS system, `/usr/bin/env` is a binary executable file, and not a directory.

Comment: Please remove and re-install, seems wasn't installed well.

Comment: Got it figured out googling around.  You need to create a symbolic link to nodejs: ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out googling around. You need to create a symbolic link to Node.js: `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` That did the trick for me.  However, I did go back and totally remove this older version of Node.js that was available through my package manager.

On the Node.js site there is a 32 bit version of node 6 LTS and instructions for installation that worked great for me on an older 32 bit system.

```
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/
```